# How to enable apiKey required to true using the aws-sdk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have been stuck here for too long. How do I enable API Key for the particular REST method using the `aws-sdk`? I could enable it using the console, but not finding a method to achieve this using the nodejs sdk. So basically want to setup the secret key for specified API Endpoint  + Resource + Method.

In the following snapshot, I enabled the api-key required to `true` from the console.

[image]

Docs referred: [AWS Nodejs Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html)

Here is what I have been able to do so far:

```
    // CREATE API KEY
    async function create() {
    try {
        const apiKey = await apigateway.createApiKeyAsync({
            enabled: true,
            generateDistinctId: true,
            name: NAME_OF_KEY
        });

        /**
         * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#createUsagePlan-property
         */
        // CREATE USAGE PLAN AND LINK API
        const usagePlan = await apigateway.createUsagePlanAsync({
            name: NAME_OF_USAGE_PLAN,
            apiStages: [
                {
                    apiId: API_ID,
                    stage: STAGE
                },
                /* more items */
            ],
            quota: QUOTA_INFO,
            throttle: THROTTLE_INFO
        });

        /**
         * Creates a usage plan key for adding an existing API key to a usage plan.
         */
        // LINK API KEY AND USAGE PLAN
        await apigateway.createUsagePlanKeyAsync({
            keyId: apiKey.id,
            keyType: 'API_KEY',
            usagePlanId: usagePlan.id
        });

        return Promise.resolve(apiKey);
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the function `updateMethod` to update your method request:

**Reference:** [Class: AWS.APIGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/APIGateway.html#updateMethod-property)

```
var params = {
  httpMethod: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  resourceId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  restApiId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  patchOperations: [
    {
      from: 'STRING_VALUE',
      op: add | remove | replace | move | copy | test,
      path: 'STRING_VALUE',
      value: 'STRING_VALUE'
    },
    /* more items */
  ]
};
apigateway.updateMethod(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

---

**So you can do the following:**

```
var apigateway = new AWS.APIGateway({apiVersion: '2015-07-09'});

var params = {
  httpMethod: 'POST',
  resourceId: 'resource id',
  restApiId: API_ID,
  patchOperations: [
    {
      op: 'replace',
      path: '/apiKeyRequired',
      value: 'true' || 'false'
    },
  ]
};

apigateway.updateMethod(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) cb(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     cb(null, data);           // successful response
});
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Great! The documentation of this method is not easy to understand!!

Comment: How do we get resourceId dynamically?

Comment: Did you mean programmatically?

Comment: Yeah but no worries! I found it.